# Multi-select list vs Html helper PagedListPager

Tags: arrays, model-view-controller, razor, multi-select

Using MVC EF.

I'm trying to get a multi-select list to work with PagedListPager.  The issue is getting the array from the controller back to the view, and then rendering that correctly so that the controller recognizes the parameter as an array.

So, the naive first attempt was to pass the array in a ViewBag.  But, when putting that in the PagedListPager, it renders as a pointer or descriptor of the array object.

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("DoStuff",  new { page, FilterArray =  ViewBag.FilterArray})
```

That renders as:

```
<a href="/MyPage?page=2&amp;FilterArray=System.Int64%5B%5D">2</a>
```

In other words, it renders a description of the array object, instead of rendering the individual array elements.

A colleague suggested building the string with Join:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("DoStuff",  new { page, FilterArray = Html.Raw(string.Join("&FilterArray =", ViewBag.FilterArray )})
```

But, the special characters get escaped, and the controller gives up and just says it's null

```
<a href="/MyPage?page=2&amp;FilterArray=45690%FilterArray%3D50247%FilterArray%3D22>2</a>
```

I was hoping the Html.Raw would just use the string as-is, but no such luck.  Same thing happens if I build that string in the controller and pass it through the ViewBag.

What we did in another page a couple of weeks ago, we needed our Export to XLS button to have the same filters.  There we captured the onclick event and built the url ourselves.  Ugly, but it worked.

The problem with that is that the PagedListPager doesn't give ids to the page number buttons, so it's difficult to capture that event.  I had started to put an id on the enclosing div.  But I got pulled off on the string version.

So, that's where I'm at.  Is grabbing the onclick event the only way to accomplish this?  A slight variation is to go looking for the buttons in the document.ready and rewrite the urls there.  Maybe even slightly uglier than grabbing the onclick.

Hmm.  My colleague is trying a variation where he captures the onchange of the dropdown so that he can put the numbers into a string.  Then, he passes the info as a string, alongside the  array.  We're keeping the array, because that works with the original submit button.

Is there a simpler, robust solution to this that we're missing?

Answer (score 1):

How did we overlook this.

I was able to just create a comma-separated string and pass that as a string parameter.  Dirt simple.

Edit: To fill in some details

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("DoStuff", new { page, FilterArrayString = Html.Raw(string.Join(",", ViewBag.FilterArray )}))
```

That produces "1,2,3".

In the controller, I have

```
public ActionResult DoStuff(long[] FilterArray, string FilterArrayString)
```

Only one of those should be non-null.  They both could be null.  If the user clicks the submit button, the array potentially has values.  If the user changes pages, then the string potentially has values.  I convert whichever has data into a List for easier use within my method.